# How to get duration of mp3 file in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5, mp3, laravel-5.5

I have just make a new web app and I need to get mp3 duration or length name, artist name, album name of file. I haven't found any package for that yet.

How can I do this?

Here is my view form

```
<div class="box-body">
    {!! Form::open(['route' => 'admin.mp3.post', 'files'=>true])   !!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('mp3', 'Choose Mp3 File') !!}
            {!! Form::file('mp3') !!}
        </div>
        {!! Form::submit('Submit', array( 'class'=>'btn btn-info' )) !!}
    {!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to get this before or after the file is uploaded?

Comment: i need this after upload file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use package [wapmorgan/mp3info](https://github.com/wapmorgan/Mp3Info)

```
composer require wapmorgan/mp3info
```

Then you can use the library as follows.

```
$audio = new \wapmorgan\Mp3Info\Mp3Info($fileName, true);
$audio->duration \\ duration in seconds
```

Comment: "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\wapmorgan\Mp3Info\Mp3Info' not found" I Think i need to make Class

Comment: Add another slash at the beginning of the namespace. See the updated answer

Comment: i added use \wapmorgan\Mp3Info\Mp3Info on top now getting exception error i think file name not getting let me fix than i will tell u thanks

Comment: Can anybody please enlighten me, what is '$filename' ?

Comment: It's the path to the file you are trying to get information

Comment: I am getting divizon by zero error. can you please help.Thanks in advance.